# How to delete JSON Object inside JSON Array based on particular key's value null?

Tags: java, arrays, json

```
[{"period":"","billing_mode":"checked","price":"1500","bundleid":0,"name":"hello stack","deviceid":"923is3j4","date":"2016-06-23","userid":0,"type":"mobile","strutid":999}]
```

I have this JSON Array inside which JSON Objects like above were there.
I want JSON Objects which has

```
"period":""
```

to get deleted.Is it possible?Please help me thanks.
P.S:This is for Java not Javascript.

Comment: This should probably be tagged with javascript.

Comment: Is this in Java or JavaScript?

Comment: If it is for JAVA then pls specify which library you have used to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want in `java` then using `java-json.jar` you can achieve it as following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

        String s="{\"period\":\"\",\"billing_mode\":\"checked\",\"price\":\"1500\",\"packageid\":0,\"name\":\"hello stack\",\"subscriberid\":\"9283is3j4\",\"date\":\"2016-06-23\",\"serviceid\":0,\"type\":\"event\",\"programid\":999}";

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(s);

        JSONArray nameArray = jsonObj.names();

        List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nameArray.length(); i++) {
            keyList.add(nameArray.get(i).toString());
        }

            for (String key : keyList) {
                if (jsonObj.get(key).equals("")) 
                {
                    jsonObj.remove(key);
                }
            }

        System.out.println(jsonObj.toString());
    }
```

If we remove a `JSON Key` While Iterating `JSONArray` then it will give following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

So i have achieved by copying the `JSON array` into a `Java collection` and used the `JSONObject.names()` method to obtain a `JSONArray of keys.`

Comment: Thanks I will try that out:)

Answer (score 1):

See you can do using this way

This is for PHP guy :)

```
    $json='{"period":"","billing_mode":"checked","price":"1500","packageid":0,"name":"hello stack","subscriberid":"9283is3j4","date":"2016-06-23","serviceid":0,"type":"event","programid":999}';

    $arr = json_decode($json, true);
    unset($arr['period']);
    echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping:)